# Write last modified time in filename

Tags: file, shell, unix, aix, last-modified

I have multiple csv-files in one folder and I want to add the last modified time of each file to its filename.

For example:

```
Before       ->   After
TEST_A.csv   ->   2015-09-02 18:10:55 TEST_A.csv
TEST_B.csv   ->   2015-09-01 15:32:08 TEST_B.csv
TEST_C.csv   ->   2015-09-02 13:24:36 TEST_C.csv
```

How can I do this by an Unix shell script?
The problem is that I have to do it on a ‘AIX Operating System’ (Unix) and its seams that the ‘stat’-command is not supported so that it has to be done with the `ls -l` command.

I found a list of AIX commands: http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/~gcg7/unix_help/aix_commands

Comment: That list is just an arbitrary list, and is for AIX 3.2. It doesnt include `sed` and `awk` which are usually available in AIX. Please find what version of AIX you have, and list the basenames of commands in /bin and /usr/bin.

Comment: The Version is 6.1   -   sed and awk are available

Answer (score 0):

There is a /usr/bin/istat program you can use:

```
DT="$(/usr/bin/istat . | grep 'Last modified' | cut -f2)"
echo $DT
Thu Nov 29 16:50:10 2007
```

Now if you have GNU-date, you can format it:

```
gdate -d "$DT" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2007-11-29 16:50:10
```

Edit: if you have gfind, use it:

```
gfind /unix -maxdepth 0 -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS\n'
2013-06-05 16:24:00
```

Comment: Neither istat or gdate comes standard with AIX (which is what OP asks about).

Comment: Since (at least) AIX5.2 /usr/bin/istat is part of package bos.rte.filesystem; without *gdate* formatting the date might be difficult. Of course installing *gfind* would be another good idea.

Comment: In any case, it is a duplicate, as noted.

Comment: 'gfind' and 'gdate' are commands I can not use   :-(

Comment: `istat TEST_A.csv | grep 'Last modified' | cut -f2` works well. But how can I format the date and put it in front of the filename?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I left in an `echo` before the `mv`. Remove it if it
seems to do what you want. (Not tested on aix)

```
for file in *.csv
do
    time=$(istat "$file" | awk '
        BEGIN{ split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",imth," ");
           for(m in imth)month[imth[m]] = m
        }
        /Last modified/{ m=$4; d=$5; t=$6; y=$7
              printf "%s-%02d-%02d %s\n",y,month[m],d,t
        }')
    echo mv "$file" "$time $file"
done
```